# this keyword vs object name when adding method to existing object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, constructor, this

```
function Foo(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.announce = function(){
    alert(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old");
  };
}

var myFoo = new Foo("John", 42);
```

Lets say I want to add a method to this particular instance of Foo (not to the others).
Should I use *this* keyword to modify the age property

```
myFoo.becomeYounger = function(){
  this.age--;
};
```

or should I refer to the object by its name since it already exists?

```
myFoo.becomeYounger = function(){
  myFoo.age--;
};
```

Which one is better/faster or is there any difference whatsoever?

Comment: Either works, though referring to `this` will allow it to be used for other objects as well (eg `myFoo.becomeYounger.call(someOtherFoo)`) - more flexible

Comment: Use `this`, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both work, but there are some risks about using the object name, look at this:

```
let user = {
  name: "John",
  age: 30,

  sayHi() {
    alert( user.name ); // leads to an error
  }

};


let admin = user;
user = null; // overwrite to make things obvious

admin.sayHi(); // Whoops! inside sayHi(), the old name is used! error!
```

By using `this`, the code would worked correctly, just take care about this kind of scenarios.

Also if you like to do reusable code, using `this` fits better:

```
let user = { name: "John" };
let admin = { name: "Admin" };

function sayHi() {
  alert( this.name );
}

// use the same functions in two objects
user.f = sayHi;
admin.f = sayHi;

// these calls have different this
// "this" inside the function is the object "before the dot"
user.f(); // John  (this == user)
admin.f(); // Admin  (this == admin)

admin['f'](); // Admin (dot or square brackets access the method – doesn't matter)
```

To learn more, here:
https://javascript.info/object-methods